java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException assistance please im new to coding
import java.util.Random;
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] numbers = new int[10];
    Random r = new Random();
    for(int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++){
        numbers[i] = r.nextInt();
    }

    System.out.println(numbers[10]);
}

}
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 10 out of bounds for length 10
at Main.main(Main.java:12)
not sure why i'm getting ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException when i want to print the 10th index to the console.
ive tried everything and nothing is working!

because Java uses zero indexing. counting starts from 0. try counting on your fingers but start from 0. you'll see why

the problem is your index starts at 0 and your max index in an array with a size of 10 is 9 so you're trying to access an index that doesn't exist in your array.
change System.out.println(numbers[10]);
to:
System.out.println(numbers[9]);
as 9 would be the last index in your numbers array
remember indexing starts at 0 and goes to 9... 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 so 10 total hope this helps!
